# Текст с выходом за пределы блока

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

Добрый день.

Есть блок с фоном. В блоке есть текст.
Размер блока тянется в зависимости от содержимого.

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/6zfcb7st/

Необходимо без использования `JS` сделать так, чтобы текст немного выходил за пределы блока вниз. Но при этом чтобы блок продолжал тянуться от содержимого и текст был привязан к верху блока.

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/umqop1qs/ (только тут не тянется)

Спасибо.

P.S. пробовал `margin-bottom: -100px;`. Не помогло.

Comment: > "чтобы текст немного выходил за пределы блока вниз" --  чтобы последний параграф выходил за границы ?

Comment: @Arsen да, и налезал на все что снизу, если есть. Но это может быть не 1 параграф, а 2, или полтора, или это может быть картинка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью отрицательного margin-bottom. Только нужно родителю задать padding-bottom или border-bottom, хотя бы 1px.

Ну и родителю положительный margin-bottom, чтобы отталкивал все, что после него, иначе другие элементы будут на него наезжать.

```css
.outer {
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

p {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает во всех нужных браузерах. Не знаете с чем связана необходимость в padding у родительского блока?

Comment: @Skywave думаю, это связано с "выпаданием" вертикальных внешних отступов. Если у дочернего поставить вертикальный внешний отступ, то он "выпадет" из родителя, если у родителя нет ограничивающих факторов. В данном случае этим фактором выступает padding, чтобы предотвратить "выпадание".

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1.5em;
}

p {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Надо, чтобы текст был у верхнего края `.container`